# SecureField is causing TextFields to clear, why?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm relatively new to SwiftUI and I'm having an issue where my text fields randomly clear. Here's the `View` that I'm using.

#### Update

> Setting the password & confirm password security to false does not
> clear the fields. The issue is related directly to the `SecureField`.

#### View

```
struct RegisterWithEmailView: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    @ObservedObject var registerViewModel = RegisterWithEmailViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            List {
                TextHeader(text: "Create an account with Email")
                    .lineLimit(1)
                    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                
                HStack {
                    Spacer()
                    VStack(alignment: .center, spacing: 15) {
                        
                        if colorScheme == .dark {
                            Image("profile_photo_placeholder")
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.white, lineWidth: 3))
                        } else {
                            Image("profile_photo_placeholder")
                                .colorInvert()
                                .clipShape(Circle())
                                .overlay(Circle().stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 3))
                        }
                        
                        VStack() {
                            CinderTextField(title: "First Name", field: $registerViewModel.firstName, placeholder: "John", prompt: registerViewModel.firstNamePrompt, isValid: registerViewModel.isFirstNameValid())
                            
                            CinderTextField(title: "Last Name", field: $registerViewModel.lastName, placeholder: "Doe", prompt: registerViewModel.lastNamePrompt, isValid: registerViewModel.isLastNameValid())
                            
                            CinderTextField(title: "Email", field: $registerViewModel.email, placeholder: "someone@example.com", prompt: registerViewModel.emailPrompt, isValid: registerViewModel.isEmailValid())
                            
                            CinderTextField(title: "Password", field: $registerViewModel.password, placeholder: "********", prompt: registerViewModel.passwordPrompt, isSecure: true, isValid: registerViewModel.isPasswordValid())
                            
                            CinderTextField(title: "Confirm Password", field: $registerViewModel.confirmPassword, placeholder: "********", prompt: registerViewModel.confirmPasswordPrompt, isSecure: true, isValid: registerViewModel.doPasswordsMatch())
                        }

                        
                        Button("Create Account", action: {
                            
                        }).buttonStyle(for: colorScheme, geometry: geometry)
                        .opacity(registerViewModel.areFieldsValid ? 1 : 0.6)
                        .disabled(!registerViewModel.areFieldsValid)
                        
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then have my view attached to a ViewModel that does all of my logic.

#### View Model

```
class RegisterWithEmailViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var firstName = ""
    @Published var lastName = ""
    @Published var email = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    @Published var confirmPassword = ""
    var ownRestaurant = false
    
    //MARK: - Validation Functions
    func isFirstNameValid() -> Bool {
        let firstNameTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "^[a-zA-Z]+(([\\'\\,\\.\\-][a-zA-Z])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$")
        return firstNameTest.evaluate(with: firstName)
    }
    
    func isLastNameValid() -> Bool {
        let lastNameTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "^[a-zA-Z]+(([\\'\\,\\.\\-][a-zA-Z])?[a-zA-Z]*)*$")
        return lastNameTest.evaluate(with: lastName)
    }
    
    func doPasswordsMatch() -> Bool {
        password == confirmPassword
    }
    
    func isPasswordValid() -> Bool {
        let passwordTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "^(?=.*\\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,15}$")
        return passwordTest.evaluate(with: password)
    }
    
    func isEmailValid() -> Bool {
        let emailTest = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", "^([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:[.-]?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,7})$")
        return emailTest.evaluate(with: email)
    }
    
    var areFieldsValid: Bool {
        if !isFirstNameValid() ||
            !isLastNameValid() ||
            !isPasswordValid() ||
            !doPasswordsMatch() ||
            !isEmailValid() {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }
    
    //MARK: - Validation Prompts
    var firstNamePrompt: String {
        if firstName == "" { return ""}
        return isFirstNameValid() ? "" : "Please enter a valid first name."
    }
    
    var lastNamePrompt: String {
        if lastName == "" { return ""}
        return isLastNameValid() ? "" : "Please enter a valid last name."
    }
    
    var passwordPrompt: String {
        if password == "" { return ""}
        return isPasswordValid() ? "" : "Must be between 8 and 15 characters containing at least one number and one capital letter. "
    }
    
    var confirmPasswordPrompt: String {
        if confirmPassword == "" { return ""}
        return doPasswordsMatch() ? "" : "Passwords do not match."
    }
    
    var emailPrompt: String {
        if email == "" { return ""}
        return isEmailValid() ? "" : "Please enter a valid email address."
    }
}
```

For some reason, wether on simulator, physical, or live preview, my fields randomly clear themselves. On occasion, if I start with email first, the fields no longer become cleared. I can't find a discernible pattern to what's causing the issue. Here is what works.

1. I can enter first and last name, but the moment I try to enter
   anything else, they clear.
2. I can enter password and confirm
   password, then email, then I try first and last name, they clear.
3. I
   can enter email, touching anything else they clear.

#### CinderTextField View

```
struct CinderTextField: View {
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    var title: String
    @Binding var field: String
    var placeholder: String
    var prompt: String
    var isSecure = false
    var isValid = true
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading) {
            Text(title)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .font(.custom("SFProRounded-Regular", size: 17))
                .foregroundColor(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white : Color.black)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                if isSecure {
                    SecureField(placeholder, text: $field).autocapitalization(.none)
                } else {
                    TextField(placeholder, text: $field).autocapitalization(.none)
                }
            }
            .padding(8)
            .overlay(field == "" ? RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white : Color.black, lineWidth: 1) : !isValid ? RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 1) : RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8).stroke(colorScheme == .dark ? Color.white : Color.black, lineWidth: 1))
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(prompt)
                    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                    .font(.custom("SFProRounded-Regular", size: 17))
                    .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                    .padding(.bottom, 15)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Log Output

```
2021-04-04 11:38:37.956603-0400 Cinder[61702:2250177] [Assert] displayModeButtonItem is internally managed and not exposed for DoubleColumn style. Returning an empty, disconnected UIBarButtonItem to fulfill the non-null contract.
2021-04-04 11:38:50.957681-0400 Cinder[61702:2250177] [LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000008d6490 'assistantHeight' TUISystemInputAssistantView:0x7ff5b1654120.height == 45   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000883250 'assistantView.bottom' TUISystemInputAssistantView:0x7ff5b1654120.bottom == _UIKBCompatInputView:0x7ff5b165c440.top   (active)>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000883200 'assistantView.top' V:|-(0)-[TUISystemInputAssistantView:0x7ff5b1654120]   (active, names: '|':UIInputSetHostView:0x7ff5b16704b0 )>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x6000008d9400 'inputView.top' V:|-(0)-[_UIKBCompatInputView:0x7ff5b165c440]   (active, names: '|':UIInputSetHostView:0x7ff5b16704b0 )>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x600000883250 'assistantView.bottom' TUISystemInputAssistantView:0x7ff5b1654120.bottom == _UIKBCompatInputView:0x7ff5b165c440.top   (active)>

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in <UIKitCore/UIView.h> may also be helpful.
2021-04-04 11:41:00.944031-0400 Cinder[61702:2250447] [AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: com.kaulfers.Cinder due to error: iCloud Keychain is disabled
2021-04-04 11:41:00.947506-0400 Cinder[61702:2250447] [KBDAnalyticsLog] -[TIAnalyticsService _registerEventSpec:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke TIAnalyticsEventSpec with name 'thirdPartyKeyboards' is already registered.
2021-04-04 11:41:09.908513-0400 Cinder[61702:2250447] [AutoFill] Cannot show Automatic Strong Passwords for app bundleID: com.kaulfers.Cinder due to error: iCloud Keychain is disabled
2021-04-04 11:41:09.921219-0400 Cinder[61702:2250447] [KBDAnalyticsLog] -[TIAnalyticsService _registerEventSpec:withCompletionHandler:]_block_invoke TIAnalyticsEventSpec with name 'thirdPartyKeyboards' is already registered.
```

Comment: I copy pasted your code and it works for me without issues on Xcode Version 12.4 (12D4e) and simulator Version 12.4 (940.20), SimulatorKit 597.13.0.1, CoreSimulator 732.18.6. Using the iPhone 12 mini

Comment: @Simon I'm also on Xcode Version 12.4 (12D4e), Simulator Version 12.4 (940.20)
SimulatorKit 597.13.0.1
CoreSimulator 732.18.6, iPhone 12 Pro Max and iPhone 8.

Comment: Try copy pasting your code to a new project. Run it, if the error is gone then its not in this code. I don't know much about possible Xcode or simulator settings but maybe they are screwing with it. I can only say that I complied it and run it without errors and was not able to reproduce this issue with this code here on my machine.